# Why does promise.join() take a function as its last parameter?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

Say I have a step in a procedure that requires the retrieval of two objects. I would use `join()` to coordinate the retrievals:

```
return promise.join(retrieveA(), retrieveB())
           .spread(function(A, B) {
               // create something out of A and B
           });
```

The documentation shows that you can also pass the handler as the last parameter:

```
return promise.join(retrieveA(), retrieveB(), function(A, B) {
           // create something out of A and B
       });
```

I'm curious as to what the rationale behind the existence of this option.

Comment: Why don't you ask the author? E.g. https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/issues

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Fact time**: The reason `.join` was added was to make [@spion](https://stackoverflow.com/users/110271/gorgi-kosev) happy. Not without reason though, using `.join` means you have a *static and known* number of promise which makes using it with TypeScript a lot easier. Petka (Esailija) liked the idea and also the fact it can be optimised further because it doesn't have to abide to weird guarantees the other form does have to abide to.

Over time, people started (at least me) using it for other use cases - namely using promises as proxies.

So, let's talk about what it does better:

#### Static Analysis

It's hard to statically analyse `Promise.all` since it works on an array with an unknown types of promises of potentially different types. `Promise.join` can be typed since it can be seen as taking a tuple - so for example for the 3 promises case you can give it a type signature of `(Promise<S>, Promise<U>, Promise<T>, ((S,U,T) -> Promise<K> | K)) -> Promise<K>` which simply can't be done in a type safe way for `Promise.all`.

#### Proxying

It's very clean to use when writing promise code in the proxying style:

```
var user = getUser();
var comments = user.then(getComments);
var related = Promise.join(user, comments, getRelated);
Promise.join(user, comments, related, (user, comments, related) => {
     // use all 3 here
});
```

#### It's faster

Since it doesn't need to produce the value of the given promises cached and to keep all the checks `.all(...).spread(...)` does - it'll perform slightly faster.

But... you really usually shouldn't care.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. The usage in style proxying makes a lot of sense.

Comment: What checks does `all(…).spread(…)` need to do that `join(…)` doesn't? Twice an `Array.isArray(…)`?

Comment: It also creates another promise

Answer (score 5):

> you can also pass the handler as the last parameter. I'm curious as to what the rationale behind the existence of this option.

It is not an "option". It's the sole purpose of the `join` function.

```
Promise.join(promiseA, promiseB, …, function(a, b, …) { … })
```

is exactly equivalent to

```
Promise.all([promiseA, promiseB, …]).spread(function(a, b, …) { … })
```

But, as mentioned in the [documentation](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#promisejoinpromisethenablevalue-promises-function-handler---promise), it

> *is much easier (and more performant) to use when you have a fixed amount of discrete promises*

It relieves you of needing to use that array literal, and it doesn't need to create that intermediate promise object for the array result.

Comment: Also the reason `Promise.join(promiseA, promiseB, promiseC)...` works is because that's how it was in 1.x and is kept for backward compatibility

Comment: But I'm neither calling `all()` or using an array literal.

Comment: @cleong you are using deprecated version of join that only works due to backward compat, new code should only use the new version